# Sending a post request to a django-server: How to receive the response to a specific method in views.py

Tags: django, post, request, response

I have the following problem. There is a Website using django and I know the source code.
In urls.py is a line like:
`"(r'^test(\d+).html$',test)"`
and in views.py there is a method:

```
def test(request,id):
  id = int(id)
  return HttpResponse("You're looking at the method test with id =  %s." % id)
```

How can I send post request, for example with python or javascript, to the website, such that I get the return value of test with an id of my choice?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use Python [`requests` package](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) to send a `POST` request to the specified Django app:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('your_website_address/test7.html')
print(r.text)
```